# Auth::check() Larave siempre retorna FALSE

Tags: php, laravel

**LARAVEL 10 - Sanctum.**

Saludos colegas... En la imagen muestro el código del controlador que gestiona el login.

El problema es el siguiente:

Envío la PRIMERA petición con email y password (desde postman) y se autentica correctamente sin problema. Se supone que aquí ya el usuario está autenticado.

Inmediatamente VUELVO A ENVIAR la petición (por segunda vez desde postman) y el Auth::check() de la línea 33 SIEMPRE ME DA FALSE. Puse ese código para que si ya esta autenticado, le devuelva el mismo token con que se autenticó inicialmente.

**PREGUNTA:** Porqué a la segunda petición Auth::check() me devuelve falso si ya está autenticado?

Gracias desde ya por su orientación.... Saludos...

[image: Controlador Laravel]

Comment: ¡Hola! Por favor, coloca el código de tu pregunta en forma de texto, de lo contrario será difícil que alguien te pueda ayudar. Por favor, lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Quizás un poco mas de código sobre tu implementación ayudaría mas, pero según estoy entendiendo, si bien te podés loguear correctamente, en la segunda llamada, no le estas pasando el token que obtuviste en el login, por lo que para la API es una nueva llamada y no está autenticada.

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto Postman trata cada petición como un contexto independiente. Se supone que es un cliente de API, que son stateless.El mecanismo con que la aplicación reconoce que estas loqueado es leyendo una cookie encriptada que te pasó cuando te logueo.

Para que Postman excepcionalmente se comporte como un browser dejando que la respuesta le fije cosas en uno de sus store, ese setting solo afecta al siguiente request y luego se desactiva. La cookie recibida puedes dejarla como permanente asociada a ese dominio.

Esto mismo puedes hacerlo a la inversa creando via Postman una cookie vacía asociada al dominio que se llenará con la respuesta del servidor si en sus headers viene un set-cookie que calce con el nombre.

La tercera opción es que tú mismo en la pestaña tests veas si hay un header set-cookie y lo uses para llenar un store manteniendo ahí tus cookies y luego antes de cada request, en la pestaña pre-request leyendo del store usar la cookie para poblar los headers. Está manera es innecesariamente complicada para tu caso de uso, pero es la única viable si quieres por ejemplo scrapear un sitio que bloqueé el tráfico automatizado. No sé implementa a mano para cada request sino que puedes definir el comportamiento a nivel de colección. Cómo dije, es un caso de uso distinto al tuyo

Answer (score 0):

luego de full investigación, resulta que la función Auth::check()  solo da TRUE cuando esta autenticado y si viene de una ruta protegida por el middleware SANCTUM, si no es así, siempre dará FALSE, es decir, si viene de una ruta general (fuera del middleware). Generalmente se usa para determinar si el token no ha expirado y continuar con las peticiones respectivas. Si el token expiró, Auth::check() dará FALSE en este caso, por lo que debe solicitarse un nuevo token o que el usuario se vuelva a autenticar. Gracias a cada uno de uds por su tiempo. Pueden dar por cerrado este hilo, salvo mejor parecer.